# JAXB annotations are ignored ( @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) and @XmlTransient

Tags: java, jboss, jaxb, jax-rs, resteasy

I have two simple Classes:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="address")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Address {

    @XmlElement(required=true) 
    protected int number;

    @XmlElement(required=true)  
    protected String street;

    @XmlTransient
    protected String city;

    public Address() { }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

and:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="customer")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Customer {

    @XmlAttribute(required=true) 
    protected int id;

    @XmlElement(required=true) 
    protected String firstname;

    @XmlElement(required=true) 
    protected String lastname;

    @XmlTransient
    protected Address address;

    public Customer() { }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastName) {
        this.lastname = lastName;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

resource method:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({"application/json"})
public Customer getCustomer(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    Customer customer = null;
    try {
        customer = JpaEmu.findById(id);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return customer;   // null = 204
}
```

I want the JSON object not to contain address, however GET request returns:

```
{"id":1,"firstname":"Duke2","lastname":"NukEm","address":{"number":23,"street":"Hollywood Holocaust","city":"L.A."}}
```

Running with: Jboss7, my only dependencies are:

jboss-javaee-6.0
  3.0.2.Final

```
web.xml:

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

It seems that JAXB annotations are not taking part in the process of parsing to JSON, especially: @XmlTransient & @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) are compeltly ignored.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit of an old post, but I've recently had the same issue and though I'd come back to update this post.

It seems that `JAXB` annotations like `XmlAccessorType` are ignored when serialized using `Jackson`, the serialization engine used with `Jersey` (your REST controller above is `Jersey`).

[This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jackson-user/p4q-orHYgDg) pointed me in the right direction. It seems that you should also use

`@JsonAutoDetect( JsonMethod.NONE )` in place (or in conjunction with if you are going to be using true `JAXB` at any point) of `@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.NONE )`

Using this method netted me immediate results.

You'll also want to be using the `@JsonProperty` annotation instead of the `@XmlElement` property (unless you're going to be using true `JAXB` on to serialize the object at any point).

Comment: Jackson can be configured to respect a subset of the JAXB annotations using the http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations module, which has to be registered with the ObjectMapper.

Comment: JsonMethod.NONE seems to be some resteasy stuff. Registering the JAXBAnnotations module was what was needed

Answer (score 2):

Since there isn't a standard for JSON-binding like there is for XML-binding (JAXB, JSR-222), JAX-RS impls can choose how to support it.  In the case of JBoss it appears it is using an approach that does not utilize JAXB metadata.

Comment: Default implementation for JBoss is **RESTEasy**, and that's the one my project uses. I will do a bit of research: [http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html_single/#Built_in_JAXB_providers](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html_single/#Built_in_JAXB_providers) and come back with the conclusion, unless someone else can solve it first.

Comment: @TomaszSzawara - In turn RESTEasy has a built in default JSON-bindin provider.